# Wordpress Permalink Issue Remove Auto Added Code

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Website of Wordpress In My Website When I click on any URL After complete Loading Content Page Some Codes Automatically Add on Permalink

For Example

http://example.com/wow-amazing/  `Correct Link This Link Is Fine`

> After Complete Page Loading

http://example.com/wow-amazing/#.WfB5iI-Czcs

How Can I Remove `#.WfB5iI-Czcs` this Automatically Added Code From Permalink

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That part with # is generated at front side, so it actually doesn't affect you permalink. So there is no problem if you see that.
And actually it doesn't come from permalink, it is generated by some plugin's javascript. (for example AddThis generates such anchors, if you use AddThis, then the reason is AddThis)

Comment: Hi Thanks For Replying Yes I'm Using AddThis

Comment: Then nothing to do with that. There are two ways ahead.  1. Ignore this - because it doesn't cause any problem.  2. uninstall addthis if you want to get rid if this

Comment: You Mean This Issue Reason of AddThis?

Comment: What i Can do for removing this

Comment: Of course, disable AddThis, and you will see that that anchor would be disappeared

Comment: Okay Thanks A Lot For helping

Comment: Thanks Dear Problem Solved After Disable AddThis